# Markdown adds redundant empty lines to listings in lists

Tags: bug, status-deferred, markdown, lists, code

Markdown seems to duplicate empty lines in listings that appear inside a list:

1. Single empty line is duplicated

   ```
   Single empty line below:

   Single empty line above.
   ```
2. Two empty lines display correctly

   ```
   Two empty lines below:


   Two empty lines above.
   ```

When not inside a list, this works:

```
Single empty line below:

Single empty line above.
```

[[View source code of this posting](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/0e5065a1-d762-4fe8-936b-e0da938b8a74/view-source)]

Comment: My DOM inspector tells me that line height is 16px in the code block inside a list, and 18px outside, which might make the last case look less different than expected.  It's not a CSS artifact, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, this is a "feature" of most Markdown implementations, and ours is no exception.

See:
[Markdown formatting bug with code blocks in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists/19799#19799)

For more details.

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot that I had already noticed this.

Comment: @konrad fortunately I did not.